# How to create a ToolStripDropDownButton?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, toolstripdropdown, toolstripbutton

I want to create a **ToolStripDropDownButton** which looks like the below image[image]

But when I tried to search for **ToolStripDropDownButton** control in the **Toolbox** I was unable to find it because, after some googling, I found out that it is a   *class*   not   *namespace*.

Then I googled out the code below

```
ToolStripDropDownButton dropDownButton1 = new ToolStripDropDownButton();
ToolStripDropDown dropDown = new ToolStripDropDown();
dropDownButton1.Text = "A";
dropDownButton1.DropDown = dropDown;
dropDownButton1.Height = 200;
dropDownButton1.Width = 200;

Set the drop-down direction.
dropDownButton1.DropDownDirection = ToolStripDropDownDirection.Left;

// Do not show a drop-down arrow.
dropDownButton1.ShowDropDownArrow = false;

Controls.Add((Control)dropDownButton1); //Doesn't work
```

But the last line of code is not valid and gives runtime error

> Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownButton' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

Can someone tell me how to add such a button in **C# Windows Form** or what am I missing in the code?
Platform : **VS2008 Express** (i know it's old)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that [`ToolStripDropDownButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a Control and thus, you can't add it to your form directly.

`ToolStripDropDownButton` and other tool strip items only work as a part of a [`ToolStrip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip(v=vs.110).aspx). So, you need to put a toolstrip on your form, then you can add items to it.

Code example, if you want to do it programmatically:

```
ToolStrip toolStrip = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
toolStrip.Items.Add(dropDownButton1);
Controls.Add(toolStrip);
```

It looks like your code comes from [ShowDropDownArrow example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownbutton.showdropdownarrow(v=vs.110).aspx). Check out the complete code.

Also, you can do it in a form designer in Visual Studio. Look for `ToolStrip` in a toolbox.

Relevant links:

- [MSDN: How to: Create a Basic Windows Forms ToolStrip with Standard Items
  Using the Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/571c1z99(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN: How to: Add ToolStrip Items Dynamically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229625(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [C# Corner: ToolStrip in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/toolstrip-in-C-Sharp/)
- [StackOverflow: Windows.Forms button with drop-down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803184/windows-forms-button-with-drop-down-menu) - discussion of alternative ways to implement this kind of control. One of the answers suggests to use a standalone `ToolStrip`.